# SQL Server not using index in aggregates

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

We have a large table called 'TransactionTable' with around 20 million records and there's a index cover all columns used in below query.
We also have a temporary table called '#TempTable' with around 100 records. The query we are using to read aggregated data from these tables is as follows:

```
Select 
…
FROM #TempTable tmp
INNER LOOP JOIN (
    select sum(Qty) as Qty,
    Date, 
    PackingId, 
    VoucherId, 
    CompanyId
from TransactionTable 
group by 
    Date, 
    PackingId, 
    VoucherId, 
    CompanyId 
 ) trans
    on tmp.PackingId = trans.PackingId 
    and tmp.VoucherId = trans.VoucherId 
    and tmp.CompanyId = trans.CompanyId
```

the query plan first do a index scan and aggregate on the index without any join, only after aggregation it joins with #TempTable.
it looks weird but we need a quick fix, the version 2 of query is:

```
Select
...
FROM #TempTable tmp
INNER LOOP JOIN (
    select sum(trans2.Qty) as Qty,
    trans2.Date, 
    trans2.PackingId, 
    trans2.VoucherId, 
    trans2.CompanyId
from TransactionTable trans2 
INNER LOOP JOIN #TempTable tmp2
    on trans2.PackingId = tmp2.PackingId 
    and trans2.VoucherId = tmp2.VoucherId 
    and trans2.CompanyId = tmp2.CompanyId 
group by 
    tmp2.Date,
    tmp2.PackingId, 
    tmp2.VoucherId, 
    tmp2.CompanyId ) 
trans
    on tmp.PackingId = trans.PackingId 
    and tmp.VoucherId = trans.VoucherId 
    and tmp.CompanyId = trans.CompanyId
```

but the query plan have a index scan on TransactionTable, and for each row it tries to join with #TempTable, resulting in 20 million executions.

[image]
[image]
we change the sequence of #TempTable and TransactionTable resulting in version 3, which works well, it scan #TempTable and join with TransactionTable

```
Select
...
FROM #TempTable tmp
INNER LOOP JOIN (
    select sum(trans2.Qty) as Qty,
    trans2.Date, 
    trans2.PackingId, 
    trans2.VoucherId, 
    trans2.CompanyId
from #TempTable tmp2
INNER LOOP JOIN TransactionTable trans2 
    on trans2.PackingId = tmp2.PackingId 
    and trans2.VoucherId = tmp2.VoucherId 
    and trans2.CompanyId = tmp2.CompanyId 
group by 
    tmp2.Date,
    tmp2.PackingId, 
    tmp2.VoucherId, 
    tmp2.CompanyId ) 
trans
    on tmp.PackingId = trans.PackingId 
    and tmp.VoucherId = trans.VoucherId 
    and tmp.CompanyId = trans.CompanyId
```

[image]

P.S.1 we don't want to change code in the outer-most select because it is generated from some pattern, we can only change join part

P.S.2 we use inner loop join to avoid hash join which happens in some cases.

P.S.3 we tried reset statistics, with no work

I don't know why sql engine didn't provide expect plan as what we get in version3 when we're using version 1 query, it should have done it right?

I'm looking for suggestions on

1. if we're not able to change the query, how to make the query plan better? by hints or whatever?
2. how to write better query for such case?
3. any other suggestions why sql engine not working as expected?

Comment: For optimisation questions like this, it is a good idea to post the full query plan (usually via here). It is also useful to list all the available indexes & keys on the involved tables. Also: is there any reason why you are constraining the query planner by trying to force loop joins (with `INNER LOOP JOIN` instead of just `INNER JOIN`)?

Comment: As David mentioned, please provide the execution plans of each version of the query by uploading them to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and linking them in your Post.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSpillett and J.D. for the suggestion, the plan is too long and huge number of tables involved, so I take some snapshot of the bottleneck joins and added to my post. 
the version 1 query has no picture added because it is just an Aggregate on table index - it is index scan and all 20 million rows read and calculated.